# Installation module-wysiwyg-advanced-master

Tags: magento2, module, wysiwyg

I wanted to thank and congratulate the creator of this amazing module and ask him for more detail about the installation. In fact I am not a confirmed developer and I am having trouble installing the module. Can you help me please? thanks in advance
Jeans

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
composer require <module-name>
```

or you can extract in app/code
then

```
php bin/magento module:enable <module-name>
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```